# Interpretation of a probability problem.

Tags: probability

This simple problem ( or maybe not ) came up:

I choose 2 integers from the set [1,100]. What is the probability that

$$\sqrt{xy}>x-y$$

One poster felt that the problem as stated was somewhat ambiguous as to whether it allowed for replacement or not so she apparently solved for both and gave the answers
of  $\frac{8121}{10000} $ for with replacement and $ \frac{8021}{9900} $ for without.

I agreed with these answers but suspected that the without replacement was more what the OP wanted.

The answer given is $ \frac{3071}{8021} $ because supposedly this is a combination problem and x > y?!

I do not see that answer at all.
I figured that since x and y are two different variables x = 10 , y = 5 would be a different solution than x = 5, y = 10 (if they were a solution) so clearly, order matters and this is not a combination problem. And I do not see the need for x > y.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Not sure this is a math problem.  The way you state the problem, there is no requirement forcing $x>y$.  Of course, the original problem might have contained this requirement.  Without seeing the original, there is no way for us to know.

Comment: That is the exact problem I was looking at. Exact in every detail.

Comment: Can you provide the link?

Comment: http://www.mathisfunforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=23236

Comment: Thank you.  That problem is very poorly worded.  It does not even state that $x,y$ are the integers you choose!  As such, the interpretation of the problem is up to the reader.  I would tend to agree with you that, as stated, it is more natural to assume that the order matters.  As to with/without replacement, that's a coin toss.  Half the time people mean the one, half the time they mean the other.  As I said...this is a language problem, not a math problem.

Comment: As a general note; for whatever reason, there are a lot of poorly worded probability problems out there.  It causes a lot of confusion.  If the poser is accessible, one can seek clarification.  Otherwise, you just have to guess (or solve each of the various options).

Comment: So you would choose from the first two solutions?

Comment: If I were forced to choose, then yes.  I would prefer, however, to seek clarification.  Why should I (or you, or anyone) solve a dozen problems because someone else is too lazy to phrase a single problem properly?

Comment: Not to kick a dead horse, but they also do not specify the distribution one  should use.  So...we have to guess that $x,y$ are the chosen integers...we have to guess that they mean uniform (that's a pure guess, by the way)..and we have to flip a coin to decide whether or not they allow replacement.  Even by the loose standards of recreational puzzles, this is awfully sloppy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42623/discussion-between-bobbym-and-lulu).

Comment: Sorry, don't like to chat...even about math.  I think we've said all there is to say anyway...the problem is badly worded and your interpretation is certainly sensible (more sensible, I'd say, then the one you say is preferred on the site you linked to).

Answer (score 0):

Let us take the problem at face value. For example, when we choose "$2$ integers," we actually mean pick two distinct integers in the range $[1, 100].$

We can easily see that there are $100 \times 99 = 9900$ total ways to pick $2$ integers in the specified range.

If $\sqrt{xy} > x - y,$ then we can square both sides to obtain $xy > (x - y)^2.$ We can now approach the problem with casework. If $x = 1,$ then $y > (1 - y)^2$ and clearly, $y$ can take on only $2$ as a solution. If $x = 2,$ then $2y > (2 - y)^2$ and possible solutions for $y$ are $1,$ $3,$ $4,$ and $5.$ This is $4$ solutions. If $x = 3,$ then $3y > (3 - y)^2$ and possible solutions for $y$ are $2,$ $4,$ $5,$ $6,$ and $7.$ This is another $5$ solutions.If $x = 4,$ then $4y > (4 - y)^2$ and $y$ can be $2,$ $3,$ $5,$ $6,$ $7,$ $8,$ $9,$ and $10.$ This is $8$ solutions.

I know this is tedious, but it is probably the only way to solve the problem. Good luck and hope this helped.

Comment: Hi; That method due to fact that (x-y) is squared will miss some answers. For instance  x = 1 and y = 3 are a solution but not in your algorithm $ 3 \not > 4 $

Comment: The x - y is sometimes negative and the act of squaring can reverse the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You can significantly simplify the inequality:

$\begin{equation}
\sqrt{xy} > x -y \\
xy > (x-y)^2 \\
xy > x^2 -2xy + y^2\\
x^2 - 3xy + y^2 < 0 \\
-\frac{5}{4} x^2 + \frac{9}{4} x^2 - 2\cdot \frac{3}{2}xy + y^2 < 0\\
(\frac{3}{2}x - y)^2 < \frac{5}{4}x ^2\\
\frac{3}{2}x - y < \frac{5}{4}x \\
\frac{3}{2}x - y < \frac{5}{4}x \\
x < 4 y
\end{equation}$

Then just solve probability for this.

Comment: Hi; That new inequality will produce some wrong answers. Consider x = 3 and y = 1. It does not satisfy the original inequality but satisfies x < 4y.

Comment: Same problem as below, squaring the (x-y) can reverse the inequality.